# Eclipse output blank for certain files

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have two Java files. They look similar, both look like this, except with different names:

```
public class gurgle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("wuh");
    }

}
```

When I execute one, it prints fine. When I execute the other, the console is **completely blank**, and the program **runs but does not terminate.**

The one that is completely blank came from the Princeton Algorithms [course](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/)  except I stripped out all the code and put in a class like above.

Mac OS X
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: "I have two identical code bases and one doesn't work" is likely a problem with your build configuration or something like that - you're giving us very little to work with here and we're like not going to help you without additional information.

Comment: Checked everything in the "launch configuration properties" window for both files. Same JRE, same classpath, etc, they are in the same package as well. Where else can I check?

Comment: Are you using any build tools, or are you using the java builder for both (Project Properties->Builders)

Comment: Java Builder is the only one there (checked).